# PHPUnit - assertTablesEqual encoding accents

Tags: encoding, utf-8, phpunit

I'm using:
PHPUnit 3.6.12 / PHP 5.3.1 / MySQL 5.1.30

I'm trying to compare the value inserted by a function in a database with the value I expect.
The value is a string CONTAINING ACCENTS.

So I created a xml file: expectedValue.xml (file encoded in UTF-8)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <table name="MyTable">
        <column>MyColumn</column>
        <row>
            <value>résumé</value>
        </row>
    </table>
</dataset>
```

Here is the code in the test method (file encoded in UTF-8 too)

```
public function testSave()
{
    // this function saves the data in an UTF-8 database
    save('résumé');     

    $queryTable = $this->getConnection()->createQueryTable('MyTable', 'SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable') ;
    $expectedTable = $this->createXMLDataSet('expectedValue.xml)->getTable('MyTable') ;

    $this->assertTablesEqual($expectedTable, $queryTable) ;
}
```

And here is the result I get:

```
Failed asserting that

MYTable
MyColumn
résumé

is equal to expected
MyTable
MyColumn
rÃ©sumÃ©
```

Does anyone know where this encoding problem may come from ??
Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Could possibly be the database connection

When you're connecting to MySQL (in your getConnection() method), you need to make sure you explicitly set UTF-8.

```
$pdo = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName', 
    'username', 
    'password', 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
);
```

If you're not using MySQL, you can search for ways to set the charset.